# Properly stacking file array in PHP when using name[]

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a dynamic form in which when I collect the data I put all the uploaded files into a single array, using `name='samples[]'` in the `input` tag.  Currently this produces an array in which each file attribute (for instance `$_FILES['samples']['name']`) is an array, containing the respective attributes for each file in turn.  Ideally I would like `$_FILES['samples']` to be an array in which each member is a separate file, and each file attribute would then contain a single value, not an array.  I've tried various combinations of moving the brackets around, but to no avail.

**Current arrangement:**

```
["samp"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(23) "bank account update.pdf"
      [1]=>
      string(15) "teudamichal.pdf"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "application/pdf"
      [1]=>
      string(15) "application/pdf"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpIjWlii"
      [1]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phptgVldB"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
      [1]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(30547)
      [1]=>
      int(556583)
    }
  }
```

**What I'd like:**

```
["samp"]=>
  array(2){
    [0]=> 
      array(5) {
        ["name"]=> string(23) "bank account update.pdf"
        ["type"]=> string(15) "application/pdf"
        ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpIjWlii"
        ["error"]=> int(0)
        ["size"]=> int(30547)
      }}
    [1]=> 
      array(5) {
        ["name"]=> string(23) "michal.pdf"
        ["type"]=> string(15) "application/pdf"
        ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpIjWlij"
        ["error"]=> int(0)
        ["size"]=> int(30547)
      }}
    }
```

Comment: change the way of creating array instead of managing current array..

Answer (score 3):

I can't take credit for this, as it is straight from the PHP manual page on `$_FILES` - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Reading documentation would have solved this for you.

---

A nice trick to reorder the $_FILES array when you use a input name as array is:

```
<?php
function diverse_array($vector) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($vector as $key1 => $value1)
        foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2)
            $result[$key2][$key1] = $value2;
    return $result;
}
?>
```

will transform this:

```
array(1) {
    ["upload"]=>array(2) {
        ["name"]=>array(2) {
            [0]=>string(9)"file0.txt"
            [1]=>string(9)"file1.txt"
        }
        ["type"]=>array(2) {
            [0]=>string(10)"text/plain"
            [1]=>string(10)"text/html"
        }
    }
}
```

into:

```
array(1) {
    ["upload"]=>array(2) {
        [0]=>array(2) {
            ["name"]=>string(9)"file0.txt"
            ["type"]=>string(10)"text/plain"
        },
        [1]=>array(2) {
            ["name"]=>string(9)"file1.txt"
            ["type"]=>string(10)"text/html"
        }
    }
}
```

just do:

```
<?php $upload = diverse_array($_FILES["upload"]); ?>
```

Comment: I give you +1 for now, but I was hoping for a more built-in solution, which I believe must exist.

Comment: I don't know that there is, for whatever reason, the person implementing `$_FILES` behavior in PHP seemed to do it in a non-intuitive way.  I haven't seen any way you change this behavior, so would be interested if someone else posts such a solution.